# plupload can't upload large files

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, plupload

I am trying to upload the pdf file whose size is over 8MB. I made the following configuration setting for my php file, but no progress made at all :(. Any help would be appreciated.

```
a.  max_input_time =600 // 60 second
b.  file_uploads = On
c.  max_execution_time = 3000  // 300 second
d.  memory_limit = 1280M      // 128M
e.  post_max_size = 800M   // 8M
f.  upload_max_filesize = 2000M    // 2M needs to be in {x}M format
g.  cgi.force_redirect=0
h.  cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
i.  fastcgi.impersonate = 1
```

Or I would like to ask this question. If I get "HTTPError : ~~ URL might be wrong or doesn't exist", is it that I need to check up the setting with file size? I searched for this error message, and so almost all posts take the file size as the problem, although the error message seems irrelevant to it.

Thanks.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking `$_FILES['whatever']['error']`? what about apache's post/body size limits?

Comment: Actually I'm not using apache web service. I'm using IIS from windows.

Comment: well, same holds for iis. just because you set some limits on php doesn't mean much if a limit in the webserver itself is violated.

Answer (score 0):

use phpinfo(); and see your configuration status.
i think it's a misconfiguration of your phpini file, if you are using shared hosting sometimes the provider will block overwriting the phpini file.

If you can overwrite the phpini file, look in the help section of your provider, and you'll find how to and where to place your phpini file.

Comment: Thanks Mikey for help. I, however, tested the file on localhost, and am still stuck. Any other advice you can come up with? Also, is the error message having to do with the file size?

Comment: most likely, i think its related to your file size, but to test that, and get rid of any doubts, you can upload a smaller file and see it it works...

Comment: for smaller files, it works (size is like 900KB). But for anything over 4MB, it doesn't accept